# Python: Integrate daily list into df with hourly index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have daily `weather` data:

```
           rain (mm)
date
01/01/2022   0.0
02/01/2022   0.5
03/01/2022   2.0
...
```

And I have another table (`df`) broken down by hour

```
                 value
datetime
01/01/2022 01:00       x
01/01/2022 02:00       x
01/01/2022 03:00       x
...
```

And I want to join them like this:

```
                 value   rain
datetime
01/01/2022 01:00       x    0.0
01/01/2022 02:00       x    0.0
01/01/2022 03:00       x    0.0
...
02/01/2022 01:00       x    0.5
02/01/2022 02:00       x    0.5
02/01/2022 03:00       x    0.5
...
03/01/2022 01:00       x    2.0
03/01/2022 02:00       x    2.0
03/01/2022 03:00       x    2.0
...
```

(nb: all dates are in d%/m%/Y% format, and all dates are the index of their respective df)

I'm sure there is a straight-forward solution, but I can't find it...
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to resample `weather` then join `df`:

```
weather = weather.resample("H").ffill()
df_out = weather.join(df)
```

This will keep the resampled index of `weather` you might want to keep `df` index or the intersection, or all indexes instead. Take a look at the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) and kwarg `how`.

Output (default `how="left"`):

```
                     rain (mm) value
date                                
2022-01-01 00:00:00        0.0   NaN
2022-01-01 01:00:00        0.0     x
2022-01-01 02:00:00        0.0     x
2022-01-01 03:00:00        0.0     x
2022-01-01 04:00:00        0.0   NaN
...                        ...   ...
2022-02-28 20:00:00        0.5   NaN
2022-02-28 21:00:00        0.5   NaN
2022-02-28 22:00:00        0.5   NaN
2022-02-28 23:00:00        0.5   NaN
2022-03-01 00:00:00        2.0   NaN
```

Comment: This is the best option I think! I needed to make sure the index was in the right format (it wasn't in datetime, it was str) and then the resample().ffill() extends the indexes to be the same (or roughly the same) length as the other dataset.  Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Under assumption that the 1st dataframe is named 'weather' and the 2nd named 'df'.

Let's try the following code:

```py
df['rain']=[weather['rain (mm)'][i] for i in df.index]
```

Comment: I got this error: `IndexError: index 558865 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 395`
The problem is that in `df`, I have just under 395 days of data, but since they are broken down by hour this means that there are 9476 rows.  Wheras the `weather` dataset has exactly 395 rows (one for each day)